# Using Keras model for classification with Android

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, keras

I have a trained neural network (Alexnet) as a Keras model, which should be used for an android classification app. First I convert my model into a TensorFlow `.pb` file:

```
class Model2Graph(object):
    @staticmethod
    def Convert(ModelPath, OutputPath = "output"):

        print("[INFO] Converting model '{}' into TensorFlow graph...".format(ModelPath))

        # Get the model name
        ModelName = os.path.splitext(ModelPath)[0].rsplit(os.path.sep, 1)[-1]

        # Load the model from file
        Model = load_model(filepath = ModelPath)

        Backend.set_learning_phase(0)
        Session = Backend.get_session()

        OutputCount = len(Model.outputs)
        Temp = [None] * OutputCount
        NodeNames = [None] * OutputCount
        for i in range(OutputCount):
            NodeNames[i] = "output_node" + str(i)
            Temp[i] = tf.identity(Model.outputs[i], name = NodeNames[i])

        constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(Session, Session.graph.as_graph_def(), NodeNames)    
        graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, OutputPath, ModelName + ".pb", as_text = False)
```

This graph (with an `Labels.txt` file) is placed in the assets folder of my android app.

Now I load an image as JPG file. I resize it with `IrfanView` to a 227x227 image (input size for my network and ignoring the aspect ratio) and load this image with my app (the image is called `1.jpg`).

[image]

The app starts the classification of this image (this code based on the TensorFlow example):

```
public List<Float> Classify(Bitmap InputImage)
    {
        float[] Results = new float[_mClassLabels.size()];
        float[] Output = new float[_mWidth * _mHeight * 3];
        int[] intValues = new int[InputImage.getHeight() * InputImage.getWidth()];
        InputImage.getPixels(intValues, 0, InputImage.getWidth(), 0, 0, InputImage.getWidth(), InputImage.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i)
        {
            final int val = intValues[i];
            Output[i * 3] = ((val >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
            Output[i * 3 + 1] = ((val >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
            Output[i * 3 + 2] = (val & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
        }

        _mTensorFlowInterface.feed("conv2d_1_input", Output, 1L, _mWidth, _mHeight, 3);
        _mTensorFlowInterface.run(_mOutputName, false);
        _mTensorFlowInterface.fetch(_mOutputName[0], Results);

        // Convert the results into a list
        List<Float> Result = new ArrayList<Float>(Results.length);
        for(float f : Results)
        {
            Result.add(f);
        }

        return Result;
    }
```

My android app gives me the following classification results:

- 0.8430 (cat)
- 0.1569 (dog)

But I got a different result when I use my Python application and the Keras Model. The Python application gives the following results:

- 0.2255 (cat)
- 0.7744 (dog)

Now I wonder why the same network creates different results in the two applications. What is going wrong here?

My Android / Java isn´t very well, so I´m not sure if the prediction code is right. Same for the conversion of the Keras model into a `.pb` file for TensorFlow.

Comment: I worked with tensorflow in android application before, and for me, I needed to convert the .pb file into .tflite format and run the inference on that.

Comment: Interesting. Does your application generate any error when you load a .pb file? Because my Android App loads the TensorFlow Graph successfully.

Comment: Well, I never tried loading a .pb file. I used .tflite and it worked fine. I was using a CNN with mnist dataset for testing. It seems like for android development, they are pushing for tensorflow-lite to be the core framework to use.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try it.

Comment: Often this sort of thing happens because the Python code does preprocessing on the image before feeding it into the graph, while the code in your app does not. Just dividing by 255 may not be sufficient.

Comment: My Python code doesn´t do any preprocessing bevor feeding the image to the network. You can see the code [here](https://gitlab.com/Kampi/dogsvscats/blob/Development/app.py). Please take a look at the `predict` path (I remove the line `RP.Preprocess` for my tests, so no preprocessing is executed).

Comment: @Kampi Then you shouldn't do division by 255 in the Java code.

Comment: mmh yes. You are right :)
I will remove it and test the tflite model in the evening. Currently I have some problems with the conversion of my keras model / pb file into a tflite file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. I create a new post for it because I want to share the solution.
Thanks to @Steven. Your hint with TensorFlow lite was pretty nice. So I convert the Keras model to a TensorFlow lite graph with

```
Converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(ModelPath)
open(OutputPath + os.path.sep + ModelName + ".tflite" , "wb") .write(Converter.convert())
```

This graph can now be loaded with TensorFlow lite:

```
private Interpreter _mTfLite;
private Interpreter.Options _mTfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager Manager, String Path) throws IOException
{
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = Manager.openFd(Path);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new 
    FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}

_mTfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(_mAssetManager, Path), _mTfliteOptions.setNumThreads(1));
```

Now you can run the prediction on your bitmap:

```
private ByteBuffer _mInput;
private float[][] _mOutput;

public float[] Classify(Bitmap InputImage)
{
    _mInput.rewind();
    int width = InputImage.getWidth();
    int height = InputImage.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    InputImage.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length * 3; i = i + 3)
    {
        final int Pixel = pixels[j];

        _mInput.putFloat((((Pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 1.0f);
        _mInput.putFloat((((Pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)) / 1.0f);
        _mInput.putFloat(((Pixel & 0xFF)) / 1.0f);

        j++;
    }

    _mTfLite.run(_mInput, _mOutput);

    return _mOutput[0];
}
```

But you need to add

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
    noCompress "lite"
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file. Otherwise, your model will be compressed during the build which results in a loading error of the model.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ^^
How you defined _mAssetManager?
and the _mInput has not been initialized, How to do that?

Comment: You can check the current Version of the code in my [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Kampi/dogsvscats).